# How to bind an action to a 3rd-party component inside a component's template (hbs)

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember-font-awesome,

https://github.com/martndemus/ember-font-awesome

When I try to bind a click action handler on the component (see code below) the action is never get triggered,

**Inside my component**

```
{{fa-icon "times" (action "paramRemove" param on="click")}}
```

How can I bind a action to a component without re-open the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define click attribute value using action helper.
Reference - https://github.com/martndemus/ember-font-awesome#actions

```
{{fa-icon "times" click=(action "paramRemove" param)}}
```